# viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear not called with pushViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

```
NewViewController_iPhone *newViewController = [[NewViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];


[self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

`viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` are not called in `NewViewController_iPhone`. Why not?

Comment: This has been answered a lot of times. Please check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953192/viewwillappear-is-never-called-till-i-load-a-modal-view-controller-in-the-of-th http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065978/push-view-controller-into-navigation-controller

Comment: None of these really have a definitive answer. I just quit xcode and reopened the project, and now these methods are getting called without calling them manually...

Comment: Seems to just be a bug then, sorry about that. Usually these don't get called when setting a view controller as the root of the navigation or the root view controller of the window. But isn't the case for pushViewController:animated: